# Google Cloud API 403 - Insufficient Permission

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-play-console

I would like to extract the reporting data of our mobile apps from Google Play Console.

According to [this documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870?hl=en#zippy=%2Cdetailed-reports%2Caggregated-reports%2Cdownload-reports-using-a-client-library-and-service-account%2Csee-an-example-python%2Cinstalls), we have to use `SignedJwtAssertionCredentials` to authenticate. After some errors and research it seems that the code snippet in the doc is kind of outdated (since `SignedJWTAssertionCredentials` is not available anymore). Instead we tried the following to automatically download the reports:

```
from oauth2client.service_account import  ServiceAccountCredentials
from apiclient.discovery import build

scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']
key_file_location = 'files/access_token/mykeyfile.json'

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(key_file_location, scopes)

cloud_storage_bucket = 'pubsite_prod_rev_123456789'
report_to_download = 'installs/installs_com.someapp.etc.etc_2021*'

storage = build('storage', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

print( storage.objects().get(bucket = cloud_storage_bucket,object = report_to_download).execute())
```

Now the problem is, that we receive the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dev\dev\z_10_ext_google_play_store.py", line 30, in <module>
    print( storage.objects().get(bucket = cloud_storage_bucket,object = report_to_download).execute())
  File "D:\Software\Python\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Software\Python\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 938, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/pubsite_prod_rev_123456789/o/installs%2Finstalls_com.someapp.etc.etc_2021%2A?alt=json returned "Insufficient Permission". Details: "[{'message': 'Insufficient Permission', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'insufficientPermissions'}]">
```

Does anyone have an idea? Our service account even has admin rights in play console (which normally would be to much..)

**UPDATE**

As DaImTo pointed out, I was missing some scopes which lead me to a different line of scope definition:

```
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only'
```

,'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform.read_only']

But I still receive some errors, now because of the missing access token which is weird because the .json file contains everything necessary:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\andre\Desktop\DAWSE\z_10_ext_google_play_store.py", line 33, in <module>
    print( storage.objects().get(bucket = cloud_storage_bucket,object = report_to_download).execute())
  File "D:\Sonstige Programme\Python\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Sonstige Programme\Python\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 923, in execute
    resp, content = _retry_request(
  File "D:\Sonstige Programme\Python\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 191, in _retry_request
    resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Sonstige Programme\Python\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\transport.py", line 159, in new_request
    credentials._refresh(orig_request_method)
  File "D:\Sonstige Programme\Python\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 749, in _refresh
    self._do_refresh_request(http)
  File "D:\Sonstige Programme\Python\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 785, in _do_refresh_request
    self.access_token = d['access_token']
KeyError: 'access_token'
```

Comment: You are using the google cloud storage api.  Not google play and not google analytics.  You may want to clean up your question a little.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be using the [objects.get](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/get) method

The authenticated user must have [sufficient permission](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-json) to use this method.  To start with i would ensure your service account has access.

After that i would check your scopes you are currently only loading the scope for google analytics api.

```
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']
```

This scope will not grant you access to the google cloud storage objects get method. For that you need to use one of the google cloud storage scopes

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast reply. You were right, one mistake was indeed the missing scope.

Now I have still some problems. It is currently throwing an error that it cannot find an access_token..

  File "D:\Software\Python\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 785, in _do_refresh_request
    self.access_token = d['access_token']
KeyError: 'access_token'